# Создание сложного JS объекта.

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

```
var newSkipTask = {
            "question": "hello",
            "text": "world",
            "answer": [
                    {
                    "index": '12',
                    "register": '22',
                    "value": '13'
                    },
                    {
                    "index": '1',
                    "register": '3',
                    "value": '7'
                    },
                    ...
                    ]
};
```

Как создать динамически объект вида представленного выше? Проблема с свойством `"answer"` - это массив.
Значение ключей `"index", "register", "value"` это значения `result[1], result[2],result[3]` которые я получаю в неком цикле:

```
while (result = pattern.exec(question)) {
    result[1];
    result[2];
    result[3];
}
```

После формирования Obj конвертирую его в JSON

```
var jqxhr = JSON.stringify(newSkipTask);
```

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newSkipTask = {
        "question": "hello",
        "text": "world",
        "answer": []
};
while (result = pattern.exec(question)) {
    newSkipTask.answer.push({
        "index": result[1],
        "register":result[2],
        "value": result[3]
    });
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! То что и нужно было